# Dynamically change CSS won't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, printing

I have a page that is receiving a big left margin from a global style sheet that I'm not allowed to change.  The margin is actually written inline by the script/stylesheet so I can't change it in my print style.
I was able to find a jQuery solution that seems to work in FF and IE, but unfortunately not in Chrome.
jquery function:

```
$('#page').each(function(idx,el){
  el.style.margin='';
});
```

I've tried everything from the jquery css.('margin-left','0') to using the DOM attributes and nothing works!  Any help is much appreciated.

```
document.getElementById("page").style.margin="0";
document.getElementById("page").setAttribute("margin","0");
document.getElementById("page").setAttribute("margin-left","0");
```

Comment: try: `$('#page').css("margin", 0);`

Comment: Could you please add the html or a live example in jsfiddle.net???

Comment: Well `setAttribute` will definitely not work. I guess `$('#page').css('margin', 0)` does not work either? How is the margin set actually? You mention a global style sheet and somewhere else that is is written "inline". So what is it now? Have you tried to include a second style sheet for printing only which overrides the margin in the other style sheet? I'm afraid, without seeing the actual code, there is nothing more to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

If you are using jQuery, you should use the jQuery functions because there are made for cross browser compatibility.

The Problem is that you are using an `id`. A `id` should be unique in your document. jQuery knows that you are using the `id selector` and changes only the first element.

Use a class instead. Check out the jsFiddle demonstration i have created.

#### Sample

**Css**

```
.page { margin: 10px }
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.page').css("margin", "");
```

#### More Information

- **[jSFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/VtZKk/)**
- [jQuery Documentation - .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

### Update

> w3c says: The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the id attribute value must be unique within the HTML document).

But ok, you said that the page is an existing one and you want not change from `id` to `class. That is not standard and not good for search engine optimization.

You can do this to get it work with `id`.

### Sample

**Html**

```
<div style="margin: 10px" id="page">div1</div>
<div style="margin: 10px" id="page">div2</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('[id="page"]').css("margin", "");
```

- [**jsFiddle Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/gRxxs/)

Comment: Why not `$('#page').css("margin, "");` then?

Comment: The problem is that he use an id. If you use `css` on an id jQuery will ony change the first element because ids should be unique.

Comment: It wouldn't matter. `$('#page')` will always contain only **one** element no matter how many elements exist with the same ID. Internally, jQuery will use `getElementById` or `querySelector`. If you wanted all elements with the same ID, you'd have to use `$('[id="page"]')`. And in any case, rather than working around making something work for elements with the same ID, fixing the IDs would be better.

Comment: And why should he use classes? Why do you think he has multiple elements with the same ID?

Comment: I've tried the $('#page').css("margin, "") no luck...  I also can't change the page ID, the page is an existing one, and I'm adding to it.

Comment: w3c = The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the id attribute value must be unique within the HTML document).

Comment: `$('.page').css("margin", "")`. only works for inline style: http://jsfiddle.net/VtZKk/1/ - It only resets the style back to standard or css. Use `$('.page').css("margin", 0)` to force it to 0 http://jsfiddle.net/VtZKk/2/

Comment: I've tried it every way... If I do an alert, it reports 0 back, so it seems to be changing it, but not refreshing the page so I can see it.

Comment: Please post some html, so i can provide a working sample for you.

Answer (score 1):

If margin is not marked with !important in your global style sheet, and if you are allowed to write css styles in your page, then try setting the margin in your page as below

```css
#page {
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```